# How to start any file on startup, hidden

Tags: boot, automation, autorun

I would like to be able to start a program on startup and hide it from my eyes, so I can't see it cluttering up my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to "hide" it.
 - Put it waiting in the taskbar (what usually happens when you press `-` on the top right of the program)
 - Hide it Completly

**Same as `-`:**

- Navigate to the program.exe file or a shortcut of it.

  - Right Click and press `Create Shortcut`. If you get a prompt to create it on desktop, then press `Yes`.
    [image: 1]
    [image: 2]
- Right Click on the newly made shortcut and select `Prooperties`.
  [[image: 3[3]]

  - Where it says `Run:` then instead of `Normal window` select `Minimized` & press `ok`. [image: 4]
  - Press `Win` + `R` and type in `shell:startup`, press `ok`. A folder will open. [image: 5]
  - Drag the created shortcut in to the folder.
  - Great! Now every time your computer boots, your program will be waiting for you in the taskbar. [image: 6]

**Hidden:**
 - If you don't already have AHK installed, then please install it from [here](https://autohotkey.com/download/).
 - Press `Win` + `R` and type in `shell:startup`, press `ok`. A folder will open. [image: 8]

- Right Click in the folder and select `New > AutoHotkey Script`
- Repeat last step. [image: 9]
- Right Click on the first file and select `Edit Script` [image: 10]
- Delete everything in the file and paste this in to it:

`SetTitleMatchMode, 1
Loop {
IfWinExist, ProgramNameHere
{
WinHide, ProgramNameHere
Exit
}
Sleep, 1000
}`

- Open the program, you want to run and hide on startup and replace both `ProgramNameHere` with the first word from the title of your program. [image: 11]
- Close the window and press `Save`. [image: 12]
- Now Right Click the second file & select `Edit Script`. [image: 13]
- Delete Everything in the file and paste this in to it:

`SetTitleMatchMode, 1
WinShow, ProgramNameHere`

- Replace `ProgramNameHere` with your program first word. [image: 14]
- Close the window and press `Save`. [image: 15]
- Move the second file to your desktop, in case you want to open the program again, open the second file or open the program from the shortcut (if you have one). [image: 16]
- You Are Done! Have fun automation!

**If you have any questions, comment below.**
*Took me over 30 min to make this.* Please Rate by Voting.